# Ubuntu repositories on raspbian/raspberry pi OS

Tags: wifi, apt, repository

Im trying to set up a wifi repeater on my pi using an alfa dongle. The drivers are available in both the kali and ubuntu repositories but not in native raspbian. I can find many tutorials for setting up an AP in raspbian but not ubuntu or kali. What do i do?

Comment: Use the Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: i downloaded the image before i started, i just get the name wrong a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the drivers are only available on ubuntu your only option would be to try compiling the drivers from source. Download the tar.gz file and try to compile it. It won't be very simple but it's worth a shot. [A](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=232691) [few](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-build-debian-packages-from-source/) [links](https://itsfoss.com/install-software-from-source-code/).